# Different value when iterating over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
     name        lat         lon
0    9999  25.147289  101.362893
1   10000  48.646000    8.701000
2   10001  48.646000    8.991000
3   10002  48.646000    9.453000
4   10003  48.646000    9.881000
```

When I iterate over the pandas dataframe and try to get value for each row:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1]['lat'])
```

I get `25.147289000000001`

Why the extra digits and how do I get `25.147289`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float values in the dataframe are stored at the precision specified by the `dtypes`.  What you see displayed is controlled by pandas `display.float_format` which is set to 6 digits of precision.  That does ***not*** change the actual float behind the scenes.

If you want your print statement to round for you

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print('{:0.6f}'.format(row[1]['lat']))

25.147289
48.646000
48.646000
48.646000
48.646000
```

Comment: thanks @piRSquared, what if I coerce it to float? so `float(row[1]['lat']`?

Comment: It already is `float`... `float(row[1]['lat'])` won't do anything different than its already doing.